# Bitemporal master-satellite relationship

Tags: temporal, temporal-database

I am a DB newbie to the bitemporal world and had a naive question.
Say you have a master-satellite relationship between two tables - where the master stores essential information and the satellite stores information that is relevant to only few of the records of the master table. Example would be 'trade' as a master table and 'trade_support' as the satellite table where 'trade_support' will only house supporting information for non-electronic trades (which will be a small minority).

In a non-bitemporal landscape, we would model it as a parent-child relationship. My question is: in a bitemporal world, should such a use case be still modeled as a two-table parent-child relationship with 4 temporal columns on both tables? I don't see a reason why it can't be done, but the question of "should it be done" is quite hazy in my mind. Any gurus to help me out with the rationale behind the choice?

Pros:

1. Normalization

Cons:

1. Additional table and temporal columns to maintain and manage via DAO's
2. Defining performant join conditions

I believe this should be a pretty common use-case and wanted to know if there are any best practices that I can benefit from.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Bitemporal data management and foreign keys can be quite tricky. For a master-satellite relationship between bitemporal tables, an "artificial key" needs to be introduced in the master table that is not unique but identical for different temporal or historical versions of an object. This key is referenced from the satellite. When joining the two tables a bitemporal context (T_TIME, V_TIME) where T_TIME is the transaction time and V_TIME is the valid time must be given for the join. The join would be something like the following:

```
SELECT m.*, s.* 
  FROM master m
  LEFT JOIN satellite s 
    ON m.key = s.master_key
   AND <V_TIME> between s.valid_from and s.valid_to
   AND <T_TIME> between s.t_from and s.t_to
 WHERE <V_TIME> between m.valid_from and m.valid_to
   AND <T_TIME> between m.t_from and m.t_to
```

In this query the valid period is given by the columns `valid_from` and `valid_to` and the transaction period is given by the columns `t_from` and `t_to` for both the master and the satellite table. The artificial key in the master is given by the column `m.key` and the reference to this key by `s.master_key`. A left outer join is used to retrieve also those entries of the master table for which there is no corresponding entry in the satellite table.

As you have noted above, this join condition is likely to be slow. 
On the other hand this layout may be more space efficient in that if only the master data (in able trade) or only the satellite data (in table trade_support) is updated, this will only require a new entry in the respective table. When using one table for all data, a new entry for all columns in the combined table would be necessary. Also you will end up with a table with many null values.

So the question you are asking boils down to a trade-off between space requirements and concise code. The amount of space you are sacrificing with the single-table solution depends on the number of columns of your satellite table. I would probably go for the single-table solution, since it is much easier to understand.

If you have any chance to switch database technology, a document oriented database might make more sense. I have written a prototype of a bitemporal scala layer based on mongodb, which is available here:

https://github.com/1123/bitemporaldb

This will allow you to work without joins, and with a more flexible structure of your trade data.